# Maximize amount of pairs in an array

Tags: c, arrays

This is my first post here and i hope it follows the rules. I'd also like to thank the whole community beforehand.

I'm in the second year of Computer Science, and here is the problem: I'm looking for a way to maximize the amount of unique even number pairs that touch each other in an given array by "folding" it. The meaning of unique even number pairs and "folding" has some restrictions, so here are two examples (**imagine that an array is a piece of paper that contains written numbers in sequence**):

```
int array[5] = {2, 4, 1, 6, 8};
```

In this array I would have a maximum of 2 pairs, since I would "fold" it between 2 and 4, and also between 6 and 8, making these numbers touch each other once.

Another example would be:

```
int array[6] = {2, 1, 6, 4, 3, 2};
```

By "folding" it between 6 and 4, I would have the imaginary paper like this:

```
2 1 6
2 3 4
```

Here the even numbers 2 and 2 are next to each other, as well as 6 and 4, because of the single "fold" that was made.

Some things to note are: I can store up to 1000 numbers in the array, there is **no limit** for the amount of "folds", and a single number can only touch **another one**. So this array:

```
int array[3] = {2, 2, 2};
```

Would only have a single pair either by folding between the first two or the last two numbers.

I couldn't find a way to maximize it besides testing all the possibilities, and I don't think it is a good way to solve the problem.

In the end 1 question:

1. How can I solve this problem without testing all the possibilities?

Comment: Would not `{2, 4, 1, 6, 8}` folded at `1` still have two pairs `2,8` and `4,6`?

Comment: Add some more detail and code if you have any. How many elements would be in that array which you are trying to fold and from which point you like to fold it, briefly explain so community can help easily. Thanks

Comment: Yes, there would be those two pairs, but I need the folds need to occur in between the numbers (I should've said that it had to be on the commas, sorry)

Comment: Sure, I'll provide some more details and information about the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "without testing all possibilities"? You want something other than folding at each "," and then counting the resulting pairs? Or is folding half way between all pairs (if on comma) and checking for resulting additional pairs also forbidden "testing all possibilities"?

Comment: Could you make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using the forbidden "test all possibilities" method? By the way, your question seems already quite accepted; but would you like to take the [tour] (http://stackoverflow.com/tour). It makes some of the answerers happy to see you having the badge for it.